# How to add a personal word list to Aspell?

Tags: tinymce, aspell

I have a personal list of words that I need  include in the aspell dictionary when its invoked . I need to check this from the command line first and then implement this into a PHP spellchecker plugin(TinyMCE)
I need to make changes in PHP code accordingly . Can anyone help me ?

```
function TinyPspellShell(&$config, $lang, $mode, $spelling, $jargon, $encoding) {
    $this->lang = $lang;
    $this->mode = $mode;
    $this->error = false;
    $this->errorMsg = array();

    $this->tmpfile = tempnam($config['tinypspellshell.tmp'], "tinyspell");

    if(preg_match("#win#i",php_uname()))
        $this->cmd = '"' . $config['tinypspellshell.aspell']  . '"' . " -a --lang=". $this->lang." --encoding=utf-8 -H < $this->tmpfile 2>&1";
    else
        $this->cmd = "cat ". $this->tmpfile ." | " . $config['tinypspellshell.aspell'] . " -a --encoding=utf-8 -H --lang=". $this->lang;
}
```

I tried $aspell check new.txt -p dict.txt with a simple word saved but says Dict not in correct form .

Comment: The latest PHP implementation of TinyMCE Spellchecker plugin has this feature .